# Borland C 5.5 Compiler not Working

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I am using Windows 7-64 bit.
Borland C++ 5.5 isn't working.

Test file Hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{  
   printf("Hello world!\n");
   return 0; 
}
```

> Error E2209 Hello.c 1: Unable to open include file 'stdio.h'
>   Warning W8065 Hello.c 5: Call to function 'printf' with no prototype in function main
>   *** 1 errors in Compile ***

I have already made the bcc32.cfg & ilink.cfg with these configs

bcc32.cfg

```
-I"c:\Borland\BCC55\include"  
-L"c:\Borland\BCC55\lib"
```

ilink32.cfg

```
-L"c:\Borland\BCC55\lib"
```

:confused:

Comment: You're sure the environment variables are under `c:\Borland\BCC55\include`

Comment: If your compiler cannot find its `<stdio.h>` header, you have an installation/configuration problem (or, occasionally, a command line option problem).  Revisit the install and configuration guide; read it; re-read it; re-read it once more.  Something is seriously wrong.  If all else fails, uninstall, and reinstall with the default options — this sometimes works when a non-default install with you selecting the location does not work.

Answer (score 3):

First look for your include and library directory and see whether it is the same as in your borland C directories option

Comment: i made all the changes inside environment variable.